# Anyone know why my scheduled workflow does not iterate over all records in the saved search it is triggering on?

Tags: workflow, netsuite

Some back information: 
The goal I am trying to achieve with my Netsuite Workflow is to concatenate multiple text fields on a customer record on a new invoice that is created. The saved search I have for this shows the invoices from the last month, and then the workflow SHOULD be iterating through all the invoices. This seems to work, or at least show in my Workflow Log, but then stops showing that it has been triggered once it reaches a certain record.

In the picture I attached the red line denotes the last record where the workflow seems to trigger.

Any ideas where to start looking would be very helpful!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your workflow is a Scheduled workflow and it's in Testing status, be aware that it will only be triggered on the first 20 records of the saved search.  if that's not the problem, we might need more information about the saved search and its exact behavior.

Comment: Oh thats my problem!!

Comment: Is there a way to trigger a workflow as needed? That was the reason I put it in testing and "Executed Now"

Comment: I looked it up, the only way is to schedule it for the shortest amount of time in the future Just for anyone elses knowledge.

Comment: You can create a Suitelet that calls the workflow using the task module.  You can specify a menu link for the Suitelet deployment.  When the user clicks on the link, the suitelet will trigger and call the workflow

Comment: That sounds interesting. I don't know anything about Suitelets but that seems like the next level in my journey! Thank you for the suggestion